# XSLT getting namespaced attribute value

Tags: xslt

I have a xml something like below

```
<ObjectEvent>
    <NodeA xmlns:abc="http://test.google.com">test123</NodeA>
</ObjectEvent>
```

how can I get value `http://test.google.com` from nodeA.

Comment: XML is case-sensitive: `</NodeA>` does not close `<nodeA>`.

Comment: updated input as specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a **well-formed** input:

```
<ObjectEvent>
    <NodeA xmlns:abc="http://test.google.com">test123</NodeA>
</ObjectEvent>
```

the following instruction:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/ObjectEvent/NodeA/namespace::abc"/>
```

will return:

```
http://test.google.com
```